# How to copy multidimensional array from Java request variable to Javascript variable in a JSP page?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp, multidimensional-array

I need to get the contents of a multidimensional array, passed in as a String [][] saved in a request variable, and put its contents in a Javascript variable.

The "String [][] dataArray" variable holds the values I expect.  Example:

> dataArray[0][0] = "Joe"
>
> dataArray[0][1] = "Smith"
>
> dataArray[0][2] = "901-555-1212"
>
> dataArray[1][0] = "Jane"
>
> dataArray[1][1] = "Smith"
>
> dataArray[1][2] = "901-555-9999"

This doesn't work:

> **Java**
>
> request.setAttribute("passedInArray", dataArray);
>
> **Javascript (inside JSP page)**
>
> var jsArray = <%= request.getAttribute("passedInArray");%>

How can I get the contents of passedInArray into jsArray?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would use a JSON library to convert it to a string and assign that to jsArray like so `var jsArray = [["Joe", "Smith", "901-555-1212"], ["Jane", "Smith", "901-555-9999"]]` as JavaScript can natively read that. http://json.org/ has a list of available libraries.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSON.  Does it take long to pick up?

Comment: Not at all, particularly when you're using a library, you won't even need to understand the JSON itself. Basically it's a way of serializing data that has a nested hashmap/array structure. So you serialize it on the Java side and JavaScript deserializes it. **JSON** Stands for **J** ava **S** cript  **O** bject **N** otation which gives away that Javascript can natively read the serialized string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use a `String[][]`, you would need to iterate over the rows in `passedInArray` on the server side.

```
var dataArray = new Array();

<c:forEach var="row" items="${passedInArray}">
    dataArray.push(['${row[0]}', '${row[1]}', '${row[2]}']);
</c:forEach>
```

An alternative would be to serialize your array into a JSON string.  There are good java libraries like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) available for the job.  Basically, they would be accomplishing the same as if you were to code it like this:

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        sb.append("[");
        for (int j = 0; j < dataArray[i].length; j++) {
            sb.append("'" + dataArray[i][j] + "'");
            if (j < dataArray[i].length-1)
                sb.append(',');
        }
        sb.append("]");
        if (i < dataArray.length-1)
            sb.append(',');
    }       
    sb.append("]");
    request.setAttribute("passedInArray", sb.toString());
```

Then in your jsp, you would just declare it as a javascript variable and use it:

```
    var dataArray = ${passedInArray};
    console.log(dataArray.length);
    console.log(dataArray[0].length);
```

No matter how you do it, you need to do work on the server side to transform your java array into String(s) that javascript can use directly.

Comment: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '0' not found on type java.lang.String

Comment: Are you sure that the `passedInArray` you used is a `String[][]` and not a `String[]`?

Comment: Yes. But for some reason, that's actually not happening anymore.  However, dataArray is now returning only two "rows".  I put in some debugging code like this:

console.log("passedInArray rowSize = " + passedInArray.length);
console.log("passedInArray colSize = " + passedInArray[0].length);

rowSize shows 1767, which is what I'm expecting. colSize is showing 2, which isn't right.

Comment: Should I be nesting the <c:forEach> tags?  If so, how would I do that? I know I'm really close to getting this thing right...thanks!  :)

Comment: My mistake - I had been limiting the rows to 2 elements each in my example.  I edited it to use 3 columns, and added an example of JSON serialization.

Comment: Adding three columns doesn't help.  See, the array is type String [][], a "row" and "column".  The result set will vary in both rows and columns.  There may be a result set with 5 rows and 7 columns, or 1000 rows and 9 columns.  But the result set will always be "passedInArray[X][Y]".  If I use the example above with push(['${row[0]}', '${row[1]}', '${row[2]}']), I will always have at most three columns, even though passedInArray may have a different number.

Comment: For example, this time, there might only be two rows and columns passed in:  passedInArray[0][0]="Joe", passedInArray[0][1]="Smith".  But next time, there might be one row and four columns: passedInArray[0][0]="Joe", passedInArray[0][1]="Smith", passedInArray[0][2]="9/23/2013", passedInArray[0][3]="Single".

Comment: In that case, try serializing the array to a JSON string as in the example I added in my edit.